# Talking in shul

Tags: halacha, synagogue, speech-talking

Most pasken according to the Shulchan Arukh that mundane talk in shul during tefilot is forbidden.
With some exceptions: [Is mundane speech allowed in shul?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/25796/is-mundane-speech-allowed-in-shul).

Is there anywhere a halachic point of view that talking may be permitted, and that it does not have a negative affect on the tefilot?
Can members of a shul halachically stop people from talking? Can anyone provide any sources as to why you may be allowed to?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16269/472

Comment: Related answer: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16285

Comment: You seem to be confusing talking in a synagogue in general with talking during parts of the prayers where it is forbidden to interrupt with talking. Under certain circumstances, there are different opinions about the former. The latter seems to be the topic of interest to you though, right?

Comment: "Machatzis ha-Shekel, Aruch ha-Shulchan, and Shulchan ha-Tahor maintain that the Bach permits even idle talk between aliyos." part of this post: http://parsha.blogspot.com/2006/07/why-i-support-talking-in-shul_26.html where I was quoting this article: http://www.torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5763/yisro.html

Comment: consider also that are shuls are made al tnai, such that we allow eating for a kiddush. perhaps the tnai extends to this aspect as well.

Comment: Aren't parts of this question duplicated by the question you linked to?

Comment: In other words, "X is forbidden. Can anyone find me sources saying X is permitted?"

Comment: There is a huge difference between “is it permitted,” “does it have a negative impact,” and “can shul members stop others from talking.” Which are you asking? (Btw if it’s bothering others and preventing them from davening properly it’s impossible to say that it doesn’t have a negative impact. Just my two cents.)

Answer (score 4):

The Rambam (Hilchos Deos Perek 6:7) says that if one is told to be quiet and they rebuke the person telling them to be quiet they are subject to certain punishments including being barred from entering the Shul. 
The Kaf Hachaim (Siman 151:8) says it is better for one not to come to Shul then to come and talk. 
Mishna Berura (124:27) says every Shul should appoint a Mashgiach to punish those who talk during Shul.
Sometimes talking during davening or other times is okay but then it wouldn't be mundane speech it would be related to the mitzvah you are fulfilling.